# unable to run android connected app engine starter project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-logcat

I am trying to debug the app engine connected android starter app but when I select account through on my phone (android 2.3.6 and deployed the app on appengine following the tutorial) it shows these errors and prompt to force close the application.
Here is the logcat:

```
06-09 13:00:07.781: D/dalvikvm(14321): GC_CONCURRENT freed 76K, 44% free 3311K/5831K, external 518K/1030K, paused 3ms+3ms 
06-09 13:00:08.007: I/global(14321): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1308ms. 
06-09 13:00:08.398: W/dalvikvm(14321): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578) 
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[my_registered_c2dm_id@gmail.com]
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321): java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the com.testtasker.client.MyRequestFactory RequestFactory type
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.impl.Deobfuscator$Builder.load(Deobfuscator.java:59)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.InProcessRequestFactory.<init>(InProcessRequestFactory.java:80)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.RequestFactorySource.create(RequestFactorySource.java:43)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.testtasker.Util.getRequestFactory(Util.java:158)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.testtasker.DeviceRegistrar.getRequest(DeviceRegistrar.java:107)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.testtasker.DeviceRegistrar.registerOrUnregister(DeviceRegistrar.java:54)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.testtasker.C2DMReceiver.onRegistered(C2DMReceiver.java:46)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver.handleRegistration(C2DMBaseReceiver.java:191)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver.onHandleIntent(C2DMBaseReceiver.java:110)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-09 13:00:08.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I searched a lot on google and stackoverflow, but unable to resolve the error. 
I did not change single character in the starter code then why its not running.

When I try through emulator (as described in tutorials) it gives PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR.

Used software:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
eclipse platform 3.7.2
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

ADT 18.0.0
app engine java sdk1.6.6
gwt sdk 2.4.0

This is the debug stack:

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
Thread [<1> main] (Running) 
Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
Thread [<9> IntentService[my_registered_c2dm_id@gmail.com]] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))    
    C2DMReceiver(C2DMBaseReceiver).onHandleIntent(Intent) line: 124 
    IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(Message) line: 59    
    IntentService$ServiceHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 130 
    HandlerThread.run() line: 60
```

On clicking thread 9 variables it shows this:

```
com.testtasker.C2DMReceiver@4052c3e8 
Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION cat=[com.testtasker]   
cmp=com.testtasker/.C2DMReceiver (has extras) }
```

Please help me, I have to work app engine but before that this sample should run on real device.

Comment: did you change the "lib" folder to "libs" ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which "tutorial" you are using. With the ADT 18 you won't be able to run the one here http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/

Instead follow the instruction here:
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_install_setup

Also, make sure to register for the c2dm service: https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/signup, which I think is your actual problem. I believe when testing you must sign in with the same account you used in registration on your phone and the local App Engine server.

Have you customized files, or are you trying to test the c2dm service out of the box?

Comment: i followed that tutorial only. I did registered for the c2dm service and received the confirmation.Do u know what does this mean-Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION cat=[com.testtasker]   
cmp=com.testtasker/.C2DMReceiver (has extras) }

Comment: not sure what that line means, maybe post the stack trace around it? Also, are you getting the same behavior when running in a physical phone, as opposed to the emulator?